# Is there any way to direct Proguard (on Android) to save intermediate jars?

Tags: android, ant, jar, proguard, obfuscation

While having issue with the dreared dex method limit error, I have been trying to find a quick solution for the problem. My apk is being shrinked by 13k methods after using proguard, most of it comes from the libraries I use. Here's the (somewhat modified) relevant output of the build process.

```
    -obfuscate:
        [mkdir] Created dir: /bin/proguard
          [jar] Building jar: /bin/proguard/original.jar
     [proguard] ProGuard, version 5.0
     [proguard] Reading input...

     [proguard] Reading program jar [/libs/kryo-2.24.0.jar]
     [proguard] Reading program jar [/libs/jackson-databind-2.1.1.jar]
     [proguard] Reading program jar [libs/okhttp-1.1.0.jar]
     [proguard] Reading program jar [/libs/realm-0.72.0.jar]
     [proguard] Reading program jar [/libs/tape-1.1.0.jar]
     [proguard] Reading program jar [/libs/google-play-services.jar]
     [proguard] Reading program jar [/libs/AudienceNetwork.jar]

 [proguard] Initializing...
 [proguard] Ignoring unused library classes...
 [proguard]   Original number of library classes: 7170
 [proguard]   Final number of library classes:    1712
 [proguard] Printing kept classes, fields, and methods...
 [proguard] Shrinking...
```

Is there any way to direct Proguard for Android to save intermediate jars, (a shrinked version of these libraries that fits my code's needs, having exactly the set of functionalities used and nothing more), just after shrinking, but before they get packaged by aapt into a huge blob ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a customized, shrunk version of the Google Play Services, which may be sufficient to avoid the 65K method ID limit. My [presentation on creating smaller apps](https://www.saikoa.com/blog/DroidconLondon2014) from Droidcon London 2014 contains a few possible ProGuard configurations to create such a shrunk library.

Comment: Eric, thanks for replying. I am already after the process of shrinking GMS. Doing the same thing on other libraries requires understanding of the package hierarchy and manual proguard configuration. From your answer I understand that there's no way of getting an intermediate jar from the shrink process.

Comment: ProGuard treats the program code and the libraries as one big blob of code to be shrunk/optimized/obfuscated, so there are no intermediate jars indeed. Considering the large number of input classes and the relatively small number of output classes for your app, it should be possible to shrink the largest libraries to a manageable size. With short configurations like in the presentation, it really isn't that hard. Note that the example configurations only keep the parts of the GPS library that are relevant to a particular app.